# how many characters are there in line in a console?

Tags: python, shell

How can I find out how may character are there in a line before the end line in an interactive shell using python? (Usually 80)

Comment: Very rarely 80, unless your Linux system broke and you're stuck in the console fixing it.

Comment: You're right, in my console I've 141 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`tput`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) utility to query the number of lines and columns available in the terminal. You can execute it using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> tput = subprocess.Popen(['tput', 'cols'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> int(tput.communicate()[0].strip())
180
```

The same principle can also be applied to query the `$COLUMNS` variable as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105090/how-many-characters-are-there-in-line-in-a-console/2105139#2105139) by gregseth:

```
>>> tput = subprocess.Popen(['echo $COLUMNS'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> int(tput.communicate()[0].strip())
180
```

Lastly, if you are OK with using the [curses](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/curses.html) library for such a simple problem, as [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105090/how-many-characters-are-there-in-line-in-a-console/2105152#2105152) by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, then note that you'll need to perform three statements, not one:

```
>>> import curses
>>> curses.setupterm()
>>> curses.tigetnum('cols')
180
```

If the terminal is resized, then [`setupterm`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/curses.html#curses.setupterm) will need to be called before the new terminal width can be queried using [`tigetnum`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/curses.html#curses.tigetnum).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know specifically in `python`,
but in a shell the environment variable `$COLUMNS` contains the information you want.

Answer (score 3):

[`curses.tigetnum('cols')`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.tigetnum)

Comment: First execute `import curses` and then `curses.setupterm()` before you do this.

Comment: See also `curses.wrapper`: http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/curses.html#module-curses.wrapper

Answer (score 2):

**Since python3.3 there is another way for querying the size of a terminal.**

```
import os
```

## Width of the terminal window in characters

```
columns = os.get_terminal_size(0)[0]
```

## Height of the terminal window in character

```
lines = os.get_terminal_size(0)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

on *nix only

```
>>> import sys,struct,fnctl,termios
>>> fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
>>> s = struct.pack("HH", 0,0)
>>> size=fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCGWINSZ,s)
>>> struct.unpack("HH", size)[-1]
157
```

Comment: I have used this in the past, and it still makes no sense to me.